# Mysterious whitespace/'Missing Icon' character box displayed in Chrome (Mac) and MS Edge (Win)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I've a fairly seasoned veteran when it comes to css/cross-browser and have been at it since the good ole days of IE 6.

I've run into this very mysterious problem of a white space appearing in Chrome and a [?] missing icon type box in IE/Edge browsers.

[image: MS Edge 11 via Browserstack]

[image: Chrome 77 on Mac 10.12.6]

[image: White space added to Chrome page source]

[image: Box in Firefox source]

This does not occur on the frontend in Safari/Firefox (however a box does appear in FF view source - see above)

The weird part is there is no whitespace added in my text editor and no special styling applied to the paragraph. I'm also not seeing anything relevant in dev tools.

Anyone know what's up with this? I've spent a lot of time on it and am stumped!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the website in Edge and the console will show warnings `HTML1424: Invalid character` and it points to the `[?]` icon.

I copy the `[?]Sat-Sun` into a txt file, then it will show the `[?]` icon. But if I copy it into a code editor such as Visual Studio, it only shows `Sat-Sun` and when I run the page in Edge it shows `[?]Sat-Sun` in browser. So the invalid character may can't be seen in your code editor.

My solution is to copy `[?]Sat-Sun` into a txt file and then delete the `[?]` icon in it. Then copy the `Sat-Sun` from the txt file to the code editor. After this, the page in the browsers will show normal. You could also try this to remove the invalid characters.

Comment: Thank you so much Yu Zhou!! Sure enough, there was a weird character that my Atom editor couldn't see: <0x03> I opened my PHP file via FTP in Sublime, removed the end-of-text character, saved and that fixed it! Wow. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to look up your PHP code. In some cases, if you write a PHP code that is not needed or Repeated in the file, browsers read it as space. I had the same issue and got back to cleaning my code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: There was a weird character that my Atom editor couldn't see: <0x03> I opened my PHP file via FTP in Sublime, removed the end-of-text character, saved and that fixed it. Mad props to Yu Zhou for the hint